# Rendering IE7 in Mac OSX

Tags: macos, mac, internet-explorer-7

I know there is Wine IE7 for mac but its super unstable and difficult to use, is there any better way to test IE7 rendering on a mac?

EDIT: I don't want to drop several hundred bucks on parrells/windows either.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a website, you can use the free online service of [IE NetRenderer](http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/) :

> IE NetRendererallows you to check how
>   a website is rendered by Internet
>   Explorer 7, 6 or 5.5, as seen from a
>   high speed datacenter located in
>   Germany.

If you don't have a website, it is easy to make yourself one using the free Dynamic DNS service of [DynDNS](http://www.dyndns.com/).

This method only works for the testing of static web-pages. For dynamic pages, a solution would to use [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) that does support Virtual PC, so can be used with Microsoft's [Internet Explorer Application Compatibility VPC Image](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en).

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox) :

> Hard disks are emulated in one of
>   three disk image formats: a
>   VirtualBox-specific container format
>   called "Virtual Disk Image" (VDI)
>   which are stored as files (with a .vdi
>   suffix) on the host operating system ;
>   VMware Virtual Machine Disk Format
>   (VMDK); and **Microsoft Virtual PC VHD**
>   format. **This means that a VirtualBox
>   virtual machine can be set up to use disks that were created in** VMware or
>   **Microsoft Virtual PC** as well as its
>   own native format. VirtualBox can also
>   connect to iSCSI targets and to raw
>   partitions on the host, using either
>   as virtual hard disks. VirtualBox
>   emulates IDE, SCSI, SATA and SAS
>   controllers to which Hard Drives can
>   be attached.

Comment: IE NetRender doesn't provide full size screenshots and its not practical for testing stuff like modal windows, etc...

Comment: Added info about using VirtualBox.

Comment: According to this post: http://blog.ryanparman.com/2009/06/30/run-ie6-ie7-ie8-images-virtualbox-macosx/  these VPC images only work with some proprietary microsoft thing, not virtualbox. Not so?

Comment: This article dates from 1.5 years ago. Much could have changed since then.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice way to do it.

http://blog.mozmonkey.com/2008/vpc-ie6-ie7-ie8-on-mac-os-x/

> The good news is that Microsoft
>   provides free VirtualPC disk images
>   for each of their browsers.
>
> The bad news is that they wont run on
>   Mac and VirtualPC wont run inside
>   Parallels or VMWare Fusion — but I’ve
>   found a solution! We can convert the
>   disk images to work for VMWare Fusion
>   or VirtualBox.

Comment: Problem with this method is that you need a windows machine to do the conversion described in the first step. Otherwise it would be perfect.

Comment: @Thomas: You can't have everything...

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [Browserling](http://www.browserling.com/). The advantage compared to other, similar solutions (at least those I know of), is that the page is interactive.

Answer (score 0):

Within Safari open the Preferences menu. Click the Advanced tab and checkmark "Show Develop Menu in menu bar". You now have the tools you'll need for a ton of checking. Also, if you use Dreamweaver you can use the checking tools in that for a text output of errors as well.

Comment: This is about rendering behavior and not about error checking. Firefox and its addons are available on OS X too.